# Trying to Add-Migration - Exception in Package Manager Console: "Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE"

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2015

I have been migrating my project to Visual Studio 2015 RC. I have also refactored it into separate projects. Now I need to add a migration for a model change in entity framework but as soon as I open the Package Manager Console I get this error message:

> Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE At C:\Users...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:50 char:30

If I clear the console and try again, I get "an exception has been encountered" -  with more information in the activity log. Inspect the activity log and the exception is:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: span at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.SnapshotSpan..ctor(ITextSnapshot snapshot,
>   Span span) at
>   NuGetConsole.Implementation.Console.WpfConsoleClassifier.GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan
>   span) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.ClassifierTagger.d__1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.d__1.MoveNext()

I realised that I had removed some packages that I probably should not have. So I re-installed these:

```
ModelScaffolding 0.9.2
MvcScaffolding 1.0.9
T4Scaffolding 1.0.8
```

This appears to have taken the second exception (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) away. However, now when I try `Add-Migration` I get

> Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At C:\Users...\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\MyProject\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:713
>   char:27

I tried uninstalling and re-installing Entity Framework. I noticed during install that the Join-Path error was displayed again, but package-manager continued, and reported a successful install. I still got the error when I tried `Add-Migration`

Then I opened the solution in Visual Studio Express 2013. I still get the initial `Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE` error, but I can clear the console window and I can add a migration - Phew!

I'd still like to get rid of that error message...and use VS 2015...

Answer (score 0):

There was an [error](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/249) in the NuGet VS extension. You can fix this by installing the [latest NuGet](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/615507) (not available through VS yet). This may require an update of Powershell and/or Windows Management Framework.